# The process could not read file 'C:\Windows\Temp\unc\snapshotname due to OS error 3

Tags: sql, replication, snapshot

I'm trying to do a snapshot replication. My publisher and my subscriptor are in different computers.

When I open the replication monitor I see this error that is generated by the subscription, while the snapshot agent was successfully created.

I read about this error, and I know that OS error number 3 means that the subscription cannot locate the folder. To solve it the path should be written as follows:
\computername\sharefolder

When I insert it in the snapshot path it returns me another error. The subscription is ok, but the agent returns me Could not read file \computername..... access is denied.

So I'm very confused, I don't know how to go on!

Answer (score 5):

OS error 3 means path not found.

OS error 5 means access is denied.

You must specify a UNC network share such as \\computername\snapshot rather than a local path when using pull subscriptions and/or a remote Distributor.  This is covered in [Secure the Snapshot Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151151.aspx).

After you have create a share for the snapshot folder and updated the distributor properties to reflect this you must assign appropriate permissions to the folder.  The replication agent process account must have read permissions on the snapshot share along with the other permissions described in the section *Permissions That Are Required by Agents* in [Replication Agent Security Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151868.aspx).

To create a share for the snapshot folder and grant appropriate permissions follow the tutorial in [Lesson 2: Preparing the Snapshot Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337500.aspx).

If you have anymore questions please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:-

Step1:

you need to check this stored procedure on your subscriber master database

sp_helpserver

Step2: 
Run this stored procedure on Subscriber Master Database..

Syntax:

> sp_link_publication @publisher = 'publisher', @publisher_db =
>   'publication database', @publication = 'publication name',
>   @security_mode = 0, @login = 'sa', @password = 'yoursapassword' 
>   @distributor = 'distributor'

----For example

In My system I'm faceing this Here

> My publisher = 'VINAYAKA\SERVER2008R2'
>
> My subscriber ='VINAYAKA\SERVER2'
>
> mydistributor = 'VINAYAKA\SERVER1'
>
> publisher_db = 'siva'
>
> publication = 'sivaTp'
>
> login = 'sa'--> Login is your creating your subscriber  asking one
>   login that login you use
>
> password = '1122'
>
> sp_link_publication @publisher = 'VINAYAKA\SERVER2008R2',
>   @publisher_db = 'siva', @publication = 'sivaTp', @security_mode = 0,
>   @login = 'sa', @password = 'Vinayaka', @distributor =
>   'VINAYAKA\SERVER1'

Comment: Here password is :'1122' not 'Vinayaka'  you can use your password